# Ros will not launch ROS_openTLD

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosrun, beginner, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't why.. I created a workspace cloned ROS_openTLD from https://github.com/Ronan0912/ros_opentld into /src/
source the setup.bash..

but for no reason is ROS not able to find it..
I mean.. it so silly why can't i find it..

Here is the the complete workspace

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=17294440767737487671

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207525/ros-will-not-launch-ros_opentld/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2015-04-21**:
Did you do a catkin_init_workspace and catkin_make? And then source the devel/setup.bash, or just add it to .bashrc?

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-04-21**:
i did exactly all of that... init workspace, catkin_make, devel/setup.bash..

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-04-21**:
edit workspace added to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code works for me just fine on Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

Make sure you're sourcing your workspace correctly and using the correct name when searching for your packages. It's easy to screw up, and I actually messed it up myself when I was testing your code.

First I deleted your existing build and devel folders, just to make sure I was starting fresh. Then, using notes I've kept for building packages, this is what I did.

```
mkdir -p ~/testopenTLD/src
cd ~/testopenTLD/src
catkin_init_workspace
cd ..
catkin_make
echo "source ~/testopenTLD/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

At this point I **opened a new bash terminal** to ensure the update .bashrc was loaded and confirmed your packages were accessable with:

```
rospack list | grep -i tld
```

and I see:

```
tld_msgs /home/chris/testopenTLD/src/ros_opentld/tld_msgs
tld_tracker /home/chris/testopenTLD/src/ros_opentld/tld_tracker
```

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2015-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1